# Oracle: how to group by 1st value in row?

Tags: sql, oracle

Table has 3 columns in a table: ITEM, SUB_ITEM, DATE_CREATED.

```
ITEM - item id (string)
SUB_ITEM - item id (int)
DATE_CREATE - date the SUB_ITEM was created (date)
```

Scenario:

1. There are 3 Different item's (AAA1, AAB2, ABB3)
2. All 3 of these item's have multiple sub-items.
3. Each item has a sub-item that is the same for each of them (eg. All 3 of the item's have a SUB_ITEM = 101010)

I am trying to do something like:

```
select * 
from table 
group by ITEM, SUB_ITEM, DATE_CREATED
```

How do you make it display only 1 row? I don't care if it chooses AAA1 or AAB2 or ABB3, I just want it to pick 1 and remove the rest so it will show 1 row per SUB_ITEM, but still displays at least one of the parent items.

Edit:

Thank you to **mathguy** for answering the above question.

Question 2:
Is it possible to group by the 1st 2 letters of the item in addition to the sub_item? So instead of returning 1 row, return 2 rows: AAA1 and AAB2 will cascade in to 1 row, and ABB3 will be the 2nd row because 'AA' and 'AB' are different.

Edit 2: See Main Answer comments for answer to question 2

Comment: Can you provide some sample tabular data and expected output based on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to group by `sub_item`, and take the `max` or `min` over another column (let's say `max` over `date_created`) and whatever is in the remaining column IN THE SAME ROW.

```
select min(item) keep (dense_rank last order by date_created) as item, 
       sub_item, max(date_created) as date_created
from   table_name
group by sub_item
;
```

Comment: I adapted this to my solution and answers my question perfectly. Is it possible to add something like grouping by the 1st 3 char's of the item? I have edited the question.

Comment: @AntonToshik - Yes, did you try? In the post you show grouping by the first two characters (not 3). Change the `group by` clause to `group by sub_item, substr(item, 1, 2)`.

Comment: yes i did try that, it didn't work, hence i decided to ask a question. But if it's meant to work i might have missed something then, ill make sure to double check.

Comment: @AntonToshik - Aleksej posted an answer which he has deleted, but in it he had created some test data which I used. I tested adding `substr(item, 1, 2)` to `group by` and it works as expected. You said you adapted what I wrote to your situation - perhaps the adaptation causes it to work differently? (Also, did you try it with 2 characters, not 3?)

Comment: the length of the sub string isn't the problem, i just wanted the syntax for the described situation in the question, the real query I am working with is quite lengthy and hard to read. But if group by sub string should work i will try to find the mistake.